# Deleting a node from Binary Tree in OCaml

Tags: tree, ocaml

I am currently exploring `OCaml` and wrote the following implementation of deleting a node from a binary tree

```
let rec deleteNode tree' value = 
  match tree' with 
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node(left, nodeValue, right) -> 
      if value < nodeValue then
        Node((deleteNode left value), nodeValue, right)
      else if value > nodeValue then 
        Node(left, nodeValue, (deleteNode right value))
      else if left = Empty && right = Empty then 
        Empty
      else if left = Empty then 
        right
      else if right = Empty then
        left
      else 
        let newValue = minValue right in
        Node(left, newValue, (deleteNode right newValue))
```

Where my tree type is

```
type tree = 
  | Empty
  | Node of tree * int * tree
```

I am looking for a review of my code so that I can improve my `OCaml` and `functional` skills.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Syntax

There are no hard rules on this, but I would change a couple things in your syntax:

- avoid `'` in identifiers. Especially in that case, you can use `tree` instead of `tree'` (there is no collision with the type name).
- usually there's a space before constructor arguments, like `Node (left, nodeValue, right)` (really up to convention, but I'd say it's more common).
- parentheses around function application are not necessary, so it's more idiomatic to write `Node (deleteNode left value, nodeValue, right)`. You can also extract a binding: `let newLeft = deleteNode left value in Node (newLeft, nodeValue, right)`
- camel case is rare is ocaml (I know, that's weird!). For example the standard library uses names like `print_endline` etc. So, I'd use `node_value`, etc.

### Replace conditionals with guards

Every time a `if` is in a pattern matching branch, you can extract it into a guard. The syntax is `| pattern when condition ->`.

By applying this to the first `if`s, we can arrive to this state:

```
let rec deleteNode tree' value = 
  match tree' with 
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (left, nodeValue, right) when value < nodeValue ->
        Node((deleteNode left value), nodeValue, right)
  | Node (left, nodeValue, right) when value > nodeValue ->
        Node(left, nodeValue, (deleteNode right value))
  | Node (left, nodeValue, right) -> 
      if left = Empty && right = Empty then 
        Empty
      else if left = Empty then 
        right
      else if right = Empty then
        left
      else 
        let newValue = minValue right in
        Node(left, newValue, (deleteNode right newValue))
```

### Use deep pattern matching

You can replace the `x = Empty` tests by pattern matching. In other words, patterns can contain patterns. By applying this to all the conditionals, we get:

```
let rec deleteNode tree' value = 
  match tree' with 
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (left, nodeValue, right) when value < nodeValue ->
        Node((deleteNode left value), nodeValue, right)
  | Node (left, nodeValue, right) when value > nodeValue ->
        Node(left, nodeValue, (deleteNode right value))
  | Node (Empty, nodeValue, Empty) -> 
        Empty
  | Node (Empty, nodeValue, right) -> 
        right
  | Node (left, nodeValue, Empty) -> 
        left
  | Node (left, nodeValue, right) -> 
        let newValue = minValue right in
        Node(left, newValue, (deleteNode right newValue))
```

### Remove redundant cases

That's more obvious with pattern matching, but the `Node (Empty, nodeValue, right)` cases also applies when `right = Empty`, so we can delete the more specific `Node (Empty, nodeValue, Empty)` case.

That's about it! Have a nice journey exploring OCaml.